# Regex in between last occurrence text

Tags: regex

I have this test string

```
[list][*] This is [bracket text][/list]
```

I want to grab all the `[*]` and after up until the last `[`

I am using this regex `\[\*(:[^\[]+)?\]([^\[]+)` which only grabs till the first `[` and leaving off the `[bracket text]` part of the string

I need the match to be `This is [bracket text]`

Any thoughts on how to achieve this

Comment: You should provide more details, otherwise [`\[\*]\s*(.*)\[`](https://regex101.com/r/kG2nX6/1) should work well for the current string (the value you need will be in Group 1).

Comment: *this works great, but the match needs to not match the last `[`* - what is the regex flavor? What tool/programming language is it for? Why can't you use the value from Group 1? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this greedy regex with a lookahead:

```
\[\*\] *(.*)(?=\[)
```

`.*` is greedy to make sure to match until assertion of last `[` using lookahead.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oB6cB2/3)

Comment: this works great, but the match needs to not match the last `[`

Comment: In that case use lookahead as in [`\[\*\] *(.*)(?=\[)`](https://regex101.com/r/oB6cB2/3)